# AE_NOT_FOUND Evaluating _DOD

Tags: arch-linux, acpi, dmesg

I have arch linux installed on my Dell inspiron 3543, fwts told me about a message in my kernal log about an acpi ae_not_found exception while evaluating _DOD.

It seems that this is related to my hdmi port which is not working.

I'm using the latest mainline kernel, I have both intel and nvidia geforce 920M and I'm using the closed source driver for Nvidia.

So what should I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: What are you trying to run with Arch Linux and a GeForce 920M!? Sounds potentially epic but still, I can't fathom what it would be! Are you Dogecoin mining?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter I didn't understand your question, if you're asking about what's not working with my hdmi port, it's a second monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a dsdt dump, check if you have a method declared like;

```
        Method (_DOD, 0, NotSerialized)  // _DOD: Display Output Devices
        {
            Return (Package (0x05)
            {
                0x00010100, 
                0x00010110, 
                0x0200, 
                0x00010210, 
                0x00010220
            })
        }
```

if not, do a bios update, and if you still don't you can try to add it and include it via dsdt override (will mark your kernel as tainted though, which means limited support on forums).

Comment: how do I dump dsdt ?

Comment: `sudo cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT > dsdt.dat`, you can do the same for SSDTs, then decompile with iasl

Comment: the result file seems binary not a text file, when I open it in a text editor I see many strange characters and question marks :(

Comment: decompile with iasl

Comment: ok I updated the bios, decompiled with iasl and still I can't find Method _DOD, now iasl says there were 18 unresolved symbols, when I gave all tables found in `/sys/firmware/acpi/tables` to iasl via `-e ` option it found 9 unresolved symbols

Comment: hmmmm the message was gone interestingly :)

Comment: attach the dsdt, and all the ssdts if you want me to take a look

Comment: thank you but the message AE_NOT_FOUND is gone from my dmesg as fwts said :)